# Setting Connections and Signal Targets using QML to python

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I am relatively new to QML and have been facing an issue with my Application even after trying out all the options stated in similar questions here on Stackoverflow. I tried to create a connection to the python script that performs the logic of the application but it returns the error:

I would like to ask if there is a specific rule guiding the where one should declare the connections component on the QML file

```
homePage.qml:12: ReferenceError: backend is not defined
```

here is my code snippet to show what I have tried.

**QML**

```
import "../controls"
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#2c313c"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Connections {
            target: backend
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: bgTextInput
            height: 50
            color: "#373e4c"
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 40
            radius: 8
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 50
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 50

            GridLayout {
                id: gridLayout
                anchors.fill: parent
                columnSpacing: 2
                rowSpacing: 0
                layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
                rows: 1
                columns: 3

                CustomTextField {
                    id: nameField
                    font.family: "Tahoma"
                    font.pointSize: 10
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.minimumWidth: 450
                    Layout.bottomMargin: 0
                    Layout.topMargin: 0
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    Layout.leftMargin: 10
                }

                SelectButton {
                    id: changeNameBtn
                    width: 105
                    height: 34
                    text: "Change Name"
                    font.family: "Tahoma"
                    font.pointSize: 10
                    Layout.minimumHeight: 40
                    Layout.minimumWidth: 120
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.fillWidth: false
                    onClicked: {
                        backend.welcomeText(nameField.text)
                        //welcomeLabel.text = qsTr("Welcome, ") + nameField.text
                    }
                }

                Switch {
                    id: element
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle1
            color: "#21222b"
            anchors.top: bgTextInput.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 15
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: 50
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 50
            radius: 10
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 66

            Label {
                id: welcomeLabel
                x: 302
                width: 700
                height: 35
                color: "#646a70"
                text: qsTr("Welcome")
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 15
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.pointSize: 22
                font.family: "Tahoma"
            }

            Label {
                id: dateLabel
                x: 331
                color: "#75a3ca"
                text: qsTr("Date")
                anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 52
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.pointSize: 14
                font.family: "Tahoma"
            }

            Text {
                id: element1
                color: "#989898"
                text: qsTr("Nothing much to see here")
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: 35
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 33
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.bottomMargin: 40
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 88
                textFormat: Text.AutoText
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font.family: "Tahoma"
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#Note#: I created some of the components

**Python**

```
import os

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal


class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    # Signal Set name
    setName = Signal(str)

    # set the slot
    @Slot(str)
    def welcomeText(self, name):
        self.setName.emit("Welcome, " + name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # main window application
    main = MainWindow()

    # introduce necessary boilerplate
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need help with this. What could be the reason I am getting this error? Is there an alternative?
I am using QtCreator version 4.12.2 community edition, python 3.8.6, and pyside2 5.15.2

Comment: move `engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)` before `engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))`

Comment: I have done this. The error continues to appear in the action output. I understand that this question has been posted here before, but I have gone through similar threads and tried them out, but the error persists

Comment: 1) With this correction I no longer see the error message, 2) Obviously I have removed `import "../controls"` since I do not know that code, 3) I have changed `Item {` with `Window {visible: true` since a window is expected besides adding `import QtQuick.Window 2.15`